# adding a background color to search term results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a background color to a user submitted search result when a user enters a search term on a page (which is basically one big table). This is a text based search. I'm using jquery to show/hide the table rows that do not have the search term as text within the TR, but I'd ideally like to take the additional step of taking the search term (the entered value), and matching any of those text terms in the remaining (showing) rows and adding say a yellow background to the word(s). I know my syntax is currently wrong, just not sure what is correct:) Hopefully this is clear...any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$("#searchsubmit").click(function () {
 var searchexp = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
 $("table tr").hide();
 $("table tr.header").show();
 $('tr:contains('+ searchexp +')').show();
 $(searchexp).css('background-color','yellow');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the `<tr>` that has 0 matches in its content, and you also want to highlight the matched text in the `<tr>`s that do have a match.

For that, you need to use Regular Expressions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

You take your input, and you use RegExp to match all the instances of the string you are looking for. You iterate through each of the tables `<tr>`, inside of which you iterate through all `<td>`, take their text, and replace the matched string with a `<span>` that is colored in yellow. You also set a variable `foundSomeMatch` to true, so after you are done with iterating through the `<tr>`, if there are any matches, you can `.show()` the `<tr>` you are currently in.

You can try it out in the code snippet below, try searching `test`, `test1` or `new entry` to see how the filter works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#searchsubmit").click(function () {
 var searchexp = $("#searchbox").val();
 $("table").find("tr").hide();
        var matchSearched = new RegExp(searchexp,"ig");

        $("table").find("tr").each(function(){
           var foundSomeMatch = false;
           $(this).find("td").each(function(){
               let textInside = $(this).text();
               textInside = textInside.replace(matchSearched, function myFunction(x){
                   foundSomeMatch = true;
                   return '<span style="background-color: yellow;">'+x+'</span>';
               });
               $(this).html(textInside);
              if(foundSomeMatch){
                  $(this).closest("tr").show();
              }
           });
        });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="searchform" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>


<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td>test1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>test2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>new entry</td><tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```